# Tabs bar (for accessing windows/buffers) as a single, one-line bar

Tags: window, elscreen, tabbar

Is there a solution to create and manage window/buffer tabs on a single one-line tabs bar?

I tried [Elscreen](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen), but it creates an annoying bars all over the buffers.

Comment: Absent creating a separate window dedicated to managing buffers, or a separate frame dedicated to managing buffers, there is no other option that I am aware of.  `elscreen` and `tabbar` use what is called the `header-line-format`, which appears at the top of each buffer (but *can* be suppressed on select buffers, if that is an option for you) -- not stretching across the top of the entire frame only.

Comment: You are duplicating your posts (several, now) on both this site and StackOverflow. **Please don't do that.** Please choose one or the other site.